# PHP cURL multi_exec delay between requests

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, delay, curl-multi

If I run a standard cURL_multi_exec function (example below), I get all cURL handles requested at once. I would like to put a delay of 100ms between each request, is there a way to do that? (nothing found on Google & StackOverflow search)

I've tried usleep() before curl_multi_exec() which slows down the script but does not postpone each request.

```
// array of curl handles & results
$curlies = array();
$result = array();
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// setup curl requests
for ($id = 0; $id <= 10; $id += 1) {
    $curlies[$id] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlies[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            "http://google.com");
    curl_setopt($curlies[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curlies[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curlies[$id]);
}

// execute the handles
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);

// get content and remove handles
foreach($curlies as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
}

// all done
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

I'm working on this all day, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**EDIT:** Any other non-cUrl method? That would also answer my question.

Comment: No. PHP's curl support does not offer that kind of functionality.

Comment: Any other non-cUrl method? That would also answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: PHP's not multithreaded AT ALL. You'd have to run multiple copies of the script in parallel. And each copy of the script would be completely independent of the others. You'd have to have some method of telling each script which url(s) it should fetch

Comment: I understand that cURL multi is only one thread that is waiting for all connections to resolve. Similar solutions with one thread will solve my problem. I don't want to DDoS any server with 1000 requests at once, but I also don't want to run the requests one at a time (too slow).

Comment: Are all the urls on a single site? or are you hitting multiple sites? If it's multiple, then hit one site in each multi thread and put a 100ms pause on the whole script. that'd make it appear as 1-hit-per-100ms on each site, even though you're hitting 5 or 10 sites at the same time.

Comment: Not really multithreaded, if you have [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) you can [run code in child processes](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/).

Comment: @Marc B All urls are on a single site. I'm pinging my own API on a different server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think you can. If you run this from the cli, you could instead [fork your script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) into 10 processes and then fire regular curl requests from each. That would allow you fine grained control over the timing.

Comment: It worked using this script: http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible.  If you use the [ParallelCurl library](https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl), you can much more easily add your 100ms delay with [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php), as you can make a separate request to be added to the download queue.

```
for ($urls as $url) {
    $pcurl->startRequest($url);
    usleep(100000);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. Script hangs forever and I'm not the only one reporting the problem: https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl/issues

Comment: Weird.  Perhaps it has been updated since I last grabbed it.  I'm using this method in 2 different applications right now, and don't have troubles.  I'll take a look at my version tonight, and post an update.  Maybe it has to do with a different modification to my copy that I made...

Comment: I confirm. No trouble at all with this method. +1. Forking cannot be used on the web. But ParallelCurl works on both the web and the command line.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not solution for that. Forking the script won't help too. In the beginnings yes but once you have a little bit more websites you need to grab like that you will find yourself as your sever very, very red. In terms of costs and in terms of script stability you should reconsider using some other idea.

You can do that with Python easily and in case of non-blocking real time calls to API endpoints you should use stuff like Socket.IO + Node.JS or just Node.JS or well, huh... lol

In case that you do not have time nor will you can use stuff like this:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.console.process.unix.overview.html

It actually all depends on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree with the last sentance :) I'm pinging always the same server (API). Server CAN hold the requests but I just want to postpone them without waiting for prevoius request to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Store a timestamp in the DB, add one handle and call to `curl_multi_exec`.
Use `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` to check timings and add more handles when you need it.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565399/813087) Daniel Stenberg (author of cURL and libcurl) says it's possible to add more handles after executing `curl_multi_exec`.