# can curl_multi_add_handle() be called repeatly?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

```
$queue = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_multi_add_handle($queue , $ch);
    }

curl_multi_exec($queue, $active)
***then call curl_multi_add_handle() second time***
    foreach ($OtherUrls as $url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_multi_add_handle($queue , $ch);
        }
```

But found that $OtherUrls added are not been fetched. Seems curl_multi_add_handle() can not be called after curl_multi_exec() been called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question has too little facts and details for us to point out any particular flaws.

But you can add easy handles to the multi handle at virtually any point in time you see fit. Until you close the handle at least.